# How to programmatically check an item in a CheckedListBox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox, and I want to automatically tick one of the items in it.

The `CheckedItems` collection doesn't allow you to add things to it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need to call **[`SetItemChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked.aspx)** with the relevant item.

The [documentation for `CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.objectcollection.aspx) has an example which checks every other item in a collection.

Comment: For those wondering, there's the opposite GetItemChecked, so you can reverse a selection by calling `list.SetItemChecked(i, !list.GetItemChecked(i));`

Comment: When I call `SetItemChecked(0, true)` then `GetItemChecked(0)` still returns `false`!

Comment: @MattArnold: That sounds unusual at the very least. I would suggest asking a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure by `SetItemChecked` doesn't work, but I found out that `CheckedListBox.Items.Add("Some Item", true)` was not working whilst `CheckedListBox.AddItem("Some Item", true)` is!

Answer (score 24):

This is how you can select/tick or deselect/untick all of the items at once:

```
private void SelectAllCheckBoxes(bool CheckThem) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= (checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1); i++) {
        if (CheckThem)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
        }
        else
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: You don't require if/else condition, in for loop you can do it like below:
checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, CheckThem);

Answer (score 11):

In my program I've used the following trick:

```
CheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(CheckedListBox.Items.IndexOf(Item),true);
```

**How does things works:**
SetItemChecked(int index, bool value) is method which sets the exact checked state at the specific item. You have to specify index of item You want to check (*use IndexOf method, as an argument specify text of item*) and checked state (*true means item is checked, false unchecked*).
This method runs through all items in CheckedListBox and checks (*or unchecks*) the one with specified index.
For example, a short piece of my code - FOREACH cycle runs through specified program names, and if the program is contained in CheckedLitBox (*CLB...*), checks it:

```
string[] ProgramNames = sel_item.SubItems[2].Text.Split(';');
foreach (string Program in ProgramNames)
{
    if (edit_mux.CLB_ContainedPrograms.Items.Contains(Program))
        edit_mux.CLB_ContainedPrograms.SetItemChecked(edit_mux.CLB_ContainedPrograms.Items.IndexOf(Program), true);
}
```

Comment: welll... this is the shortest one. :D

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you want to check the item on clicking a button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(itemIndex, true);
}
```

Where itemIndex is the index of the item to be checked, it starts from 0.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
string[] aa = new string[] {"adiii", "yaseen", "salman"};
foreach (string a in aa)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(a);
}
```

Now code where you want to check all:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int a=0; a<checkedListBox1.Items.Count; a++)
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(a, true);
}
```

To uncheck all:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int a=0; a<checkedListBox1.Items.Count; a++)
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(a, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use an extension:

```
public static class CheckedListBoxExtension
{
    public static void CheckAll(this CheckedListBox listbox)
    {
        Check(listbox, true);
    }

    public static void UncheckAll(this CheckedListBox listbox)
    {
        Check(listbox, false);
    }

    private static void Check(this CheckedListBox listbox, bool check)
    {
        Enumerable.Range(0, listbox.Items.Count).ToList().ForEach(x => listbox.SetItemChecked(x, check));
    }
}
```